# How to subtract a shape from other shape on Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Like, I have this shape:

[image]

Which is all contour and no fill. And I want to subtract those contours from another, let's say a colored circle with a slightly bigger ratio, such that the design will look like this in the end:

[image]

Which is all fill (the colored parts of the former circle) and no contours.

And yet, when I try to subtract one from the other, the result is just a circle-sized hole in the colored circle. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Have you tried to [convert the stroke to a path](https://inkscape.org/it/doc/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html) and then subtract the result from a circle?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Inkscape's `Path > Difference` only works on the fill areas of objects (no matter whether you filled them or not).

As Paolo commented, you have to convert the stroke to a filled object.

**For a single line object**

1. Select the line and convert the stroke to a fill. `Path > Stroke to path` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
2. Put the line above the circle. Select the line and the circle. Subtract. `Path > Difference` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

**For multiple line objects**

1. Select the lines and ungroup them. `Object > Ungroup` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
   <sub>If you didn't use a group you don't have to do this. If you used multiple nested groups you have to do this multiple times until all lines are completely ungrouped.</sub>
2. Convert strokes to fills. `Path > Stroke to path` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
3. Unite the lines. `Path > Union` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.
4. Put the lines above the circle. Select the lines and the circle. Subtract. `Path > Difference` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.